# ckeditor5 - how to upcast an optional attribute

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have a custom ckeditor5 plugin that wraps a string with a custom tag and inserts an optional attribute. The tags can also be entered manually. Three possible forms are:

```
[<bbref ver="RSV">Mt 2:1 rsv</bbref>]
[<bbref ver="">Mt 2:2 null</bbref>]
[<bbref>Mt 2:3 none</bbref>]</p>
```

The editor recognises (upcasts) the first 2 but treats the third as just the plain text.
My upcast code:

```
// Conversion from a view element to a model attribute
conversion.for('upcast').elementToAttribute({
    view: {
        name: 'bbref',
        attributes: ['ver']
    },
    model: {
        key: 'bibleref',

        // Callback function provides access to the view element
        value: viewElement => {
            let ver = viewElement.getAttribute('ver');
            console.log('in upcast ver=['+ver+']');
            return ver;
        }
    }
});
```

The viewElement callback does not even seem to be called for the third form.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to list the attributes for the view in order to get them in the model value callback.

`attributes: ['ver']` acts as a constraint on which view elements will be upcasted, and says "only upcast the `bbref` elements with a `ver` attribute".

```
// Conversion from a view element to a model attribute
conversion.for('upcast').elementToAttribute({
    view: {
        name: 'bbref',
    },
    model: {
        key: 'bibleref',

        // Callback function provides access to the view element
        value: viewElement => {
            // You can still get the ver attribute.
            let ver = viewElement.getAttribute('ver');
            console.log('in upcast ver=['+ver+']');
            return ver;
        }
    }
});
```